# Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml)

Tags: linux, centos, hp-proliant

I recovered a old HP Proliant ML110 G5 server. I formatted the disks and I re-installed the operating system CentOS 5.11. 
When I try to install some programs or do other operation I often receive the following error:

```
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again
```

For example, when I try to upgrade *yum* by command line I obtain this result:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum upgrade
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. Invalid release/repo/arch combination/
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. Invalid release/repo/arch combination/
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. Invalid release/repo/arch combination/
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. Invalid release/repo/arch combination/
 * c5-media: 
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again
```

I tried several solutions I found by Google, but I've not been yet able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

> http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
>   [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found

CentOS 5.11 had end of life three years ago. The repo was moved to "old versions", the vault. Please replace the files in `/etc/yum.repos` with this `CentOS-5.11.repo` :

```
[CentOS 5.11]
name=CentOS-5.11-x86_64 
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.11/os/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

[CentOS 5.11-updates]
name=CentOS-5.11-updates-x86_64 
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.11/updates/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

[epel-5.11.repo]
name=CentOS-5.11-EPEL
baseurl=https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/5/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```